# create a view in postgres with differential columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, sql-view

I have a unique table containing data mixed for people and organizations in the same columns, there's only a field with just 1 letter that sets the data reference.

example

```
id|type | surname of person/organization | name of person/address of organization | person sex/organization fiscal code
 1|   P | GATES                          | BILL                                   | M
 2|   O | GOOGLE                         | PALO ALTO                              | 04340349204920
 3|   P | DOE                            | JENNIFER                               | F
...etc....
```

I'd like to create a view in Postgres that organizes and separates information by reference type (letter), like this

```
id|type|surname|name      |sex|organization|address    |fiscal code
 1| P  | GATES | BILL     | M |            |           |         
 2| O  |       |          |   | GOOGLE     | PALO ALTO | 04340349204920
 3| P  | DOE   | JENNIFER | F |            |           |
```

I thought it should have been simple (for me) but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use case expressions:

```
create view myview (surname, name, sex, orga, address, fiscal_code) as
select
    id,
    type,
    case when type = 'P' then surname_or_orga    end as surname,
    case when type = 'P' then name_or_address    end as name,
    case when type = 'P' then sex_or_fiscal_code end as sex,
    case when type = 'O' then surname_or_orga    end as orga,
    case when type = 'O' then name_or_address    end as address,
    case when type = 'O' then sex_or_fiscal_code end as fiscal_code
from mytable
```